# С++, Обращение к свойству созданного factory паттерном класса

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Мне нужно в ходе выполнения программы создать несколько разных классов (по сути это будут отдельные анкеты для водоемов различающиеся по разному набору полей).

Для этого я выбрал **factory pattern**, проблема в том, что не понимаю, как следует после создания объекта(анкеты) обращаться к ее свойствам? Мой код:(Да, свойства мог бы и получше назвать)

```
enum WaterID {Lake = 0, Sea = 1, River = 2}

class Water
{
public:
    virtual ~Water();

    static Water* createWater (WaterID id);
};

class classSea:   public Water 
{
    QString name;
    int space;
};

class classRiver: public Water
{
    QString name;
    QString istock;
    QString stock;
    int lenght;
    int space;
    bool haveIstock = 0;
    bool haveStock = 0;
};

class classLake:  public Water
{
    QString name;
    QString stock;
    int space;          
    bool sol = 0;       
    bool haveStock = 0;
};



class factoryWater
{
private:
    Water *ptr;
public:
    factoryWater(WaterID type)
    {
    if (type == Lake)
        ptr = new classLake();
    if (type == River)
        ptr =  new classRiver();
    if (type == Sea)
        ptr = new classSea();
    }
    ~factoryWater()
    {
        if (ptr)
        {
            delete[] ptr;
            ptr = nullptr;
        }
    }
    Water * getWater()
    {
        return ptr;
    }
};
```

И еще, как удобнее эти объекты потом хранить? Массив указателей?

Comment: А как вы вообще собирались получать доступ к данным объектов, если они в private а методов у вас нет вообще. Да и зачем в базовом классе у вас фабричный метод?

Comment: Например так:  factoryWater f;    f.getWater()->createWater (...), хранить обьекты   как последовательность или список указателей. Конкретно во что хранить  выбирают в зависимости от реализации. Не может быть однозначного ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обращатся можете с помощью классического подходи геттеров и сеттеров, то есть создать в каждом классе функцию `GetValue()` и `SetValue()`(в SetValue будет соответствующий параметр), для каждого поля, к которому Вы хотите иметь возможность обращаться вне функций класса, сделав их публичными методами, то есть методами с модификатором доступа `public`, с помощью которых Вы сможете обращаться к скрытым полям класса, то есть полям, модификатор доступа у которых будет `private` или `protected`, в зависимости от Ваших целей.

Хранить лучше в `std::vector<Water*> ContainerOfWaterObjects;`, но зависит от Ваших целей, здесь решать именно Вам, что будет работать быстрее или с чем будет работать удобнее конкретно в Вашем случае.

Этот контейнер работает как массив указателей, только более удобен в использовании и Вам, в большинстве случаев, не нужно заботиться о его размере, просто добавляете в этот вектор элемент с помощью функции `push_back()`, которая добавит новый созданный Вами обьект в массив уже имеющихся.

Еще советую использовать 
`enum class WaterID { Lake = 0, Sea = 1, River = 2 };`, чтобы избежать конфликтов в случае появления энумераторов с такими же элементами.

В целом это выглядело бы примерно так на Вашем примере кода:

```
    std::vector<Water*> ContainerOfWaterObjects;
    ContainerOfWaterObjects.push_back(factoryWater(Lake).getWater());
    ContainerOfWaterObjects.back().SetName("Lake Name");
    QString Str = ContainerOfWaterObjects.back().GetName();
```

или 
`ContainerOfWaterObjects.push_back(factoryWater(WaterID::Lake).getWater());`, если решите использовать `enum class`.

Comment: Но проблема в том, что объекты хранящиеся в векторе/массивах/списках будут типа Water, как для них использовать геттеры и сеттеры?

Comment: @DartWelder, извините, действительно не учел этот момент.
Зачастую в подобных ситуациях в классе предке, в вашем случае Water есть общий интерфейс, в виде какой-то вирутальной функции, которая можем быть переопределена у классов наследников и реализована в том виде, в котором будет удобно для класса наследника. В Вашей ситуации из-за большого количества полей решение будет не самого лучшего вида.

Comment: @DartWelder, к примеру, В классе Water, Вы можете сделать template функцию SetField, которая будет по разному переопределятся у классов наследников. Это так же может выглядеть как своего рода фабрика, где 1 параметр - это конкретное значение которое вы хотите засетить, а второе - идентификатор, например название поля, которое вы будете проверять внутри переопределенной функции класса наследника и в зависимости от этого устанавливать нужное поле. Примерно такой же ритуал нужно будет провести с функцией get.